# Enable tips for function, methods etc in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, ide, tooltip

I'm confused because I can't see tips when I'm writing my code (working with Symfony 3+).

I want to see tips that will let me see each method, function etc. I want to see tips every time when I'm typing. I was trying everything but nothing helps.

I'm using NetBeans 8.2

Here's my example function:

```
/**
 * Here should be description of function that will show in tip when calling
 * that function. Also when I'll write class name i should get the list
 * of available functions inside of it
 *
 * @Route("/", name="whatever")
 */
public function someAction()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Annotations, phpdoc or DocBlock are keywords you're looking for. I've stopped using netbeans a long time ago in favour of phpstorm, but I'm sure it can support it.

Comment: I would like to second Stephan's choice. PHPStorm's Symfony plugin is by far the most helpful thing when working with the framework. It has its own weird moments, but those are getting ironed out by regular updates.

Comment: I resolved my question. I didn't mark my function as static, that's why IDE didn't show me hints. Same problem also existed in Eclipse Oxygen. After setting my function to static - hints started working

Comment: So non-static methods can't have tooltips? Can't be true.

Comment: And to be honest: suggest using paid software on StackOverflow to work with open source software (like Symfony) doesn't feel right. But not mentioning the elephant in the room doesn't feel good either.

Comment: anyways non-static methods didn't show me tooltips when calling methods from another file, when i set it to static - they do